# Connect PC to TV as gaming console

Tags: streaming, tv, gaming

I want to use my Steam collection of games and play them on my smart tv, preferably using a controller. The only problem is that the PC is in one room and the TV in another, so connecting it to a cable is out of the question.

PC Specs: Intel Core i5-750, nVidia GTX 460, 8GB RAM
The TV is an LG 42LB730V that runs WebOS.

The TV and the PC are connected to the same router, so this may be of use.

Is there a way to have the TV connected to the PC in another way besides an HDMI Cable. And if so, how will I be able to use the controller effectively if the PC is not in the same room.

Thanks

Comment: What you need is [Miracast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast).

Answer (score 0):

I may have completely misunderstood your question, but isn't this what you need? http://store.steampowered.com/streaming/

Comment: That would still require a second computer connected to the TV.

Answer (score 0):

The **[Wireless HDMI](http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/the-best-wireless-hdmi-video-transmitter/)** is the word. There are many solutions available at the market.

Comment: Ok. This may solve the image problem. What about controls?